# Маппинг строк из нескольких таблиц на структуру

Tags: mysql, golang

Я использую пакет github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql

У меня есть две таблицы:

```
create table users (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    name varchar(256) not null,
    email varchar(256) not null,
    password varchar(255) not null,
    role tinyint(1) default 1 not null
);

create table posts (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    title varchar(256) not null,
    content text not null,
    user_id int not null
);
```

и две модели:

```
type User struct {
    ID       uint64
    Name     string
    Email    string
    Password string
    Role     uint8
}

type Post struct {
    ID      uint64
    Title   string
    Content string
    Author User
}
```

Вытягиваю посты из базы:

```
func GetAll() []*models.Post {
    rows, err := core.GetDB().Query("select id, title, content from posts")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    posts := make([]*models.Post, 0)
    for rows.Next() {
        post := new(models.Post)
        err := rows.Scan(&post.ID, &post.Title, &post.Content)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        posts = append(posts, post)
    }
    if err = rows.Err(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    return posts
}
```

Как мне получить массив структур Post с вложенной структурой User в поле Author?
Конечно я могу добавить поле userId в структуру и получить пользователей отдельным запросом а потом подставить их туда, но в данном случае мне кажется лучше использовать join, но как мне подставить результаты запроса в нужные поля?

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятно в чем сложность, попробуйте так:

```
func GetAll() []*models.Post {
    rows, err := core.GetDB().Query("select p.id, p.title, p.content, u.id, u.name, u.email from posts p inner join users u ON u.id = p.user_id")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    posts := make([]*models.Post, 0)
    for rows.Next() {
        post := new(models.Post)
        user = new(models.User)
        err := rows.Scan(&post.ID, &post.Title, &post.Content, &user.ID, &user.Name, &user.Email)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        post.Author = *user

        posts = append(posts, post)
    }
    if err = rows.Err(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    return posts
}
```